# Хочу поймать все Ajax запросы?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, chrome-extension

Как поймать все ajax запросы. Мне нужен ответ responseText. Как мне это сделать?
Я использую браузер GoogleChrome.

Comment: Вы уже пробовали использовать вкладку Network, в инструментах разработчика?

Comment: @2ip Да я знаком с таким подходом. Но мне нужен моментальный ответ. Мне не обязательно сохранить responseText в файл. Мне нужен content responseText, чтобы проверить контент програмно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page

Comment: @nazarpunk Спасибо, очень интересный ответ.

Comment: `(function() {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        console.log('request started!');
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            console.log('request completed!');
            console.log(this.readyState); //will always be 4 (ajax is completed successfully)
            console.log(this.responseText); //whatever the response was
        });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();` Мне понравился этот ответ. И хорошо работает. Но я хорошо не понял origOpen.apply(this, arguments);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [AJAX hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page):

```
{
    // сохраняем оригинальный open()
    const origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    // перезаписываем оригинальный open() 
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
        console.log('request started!');
        this.addEventListener('load', function () {
            console.log('request completed!');
            console.log(this.readyState); //will always be 4 (ajax is completed successfully)
            console.log(this.responseText); //whatever the response was
        });
        // выполняем оригинальный open()
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Comment: На счёт того что вы указали адрес "AJAX hook" это хорошо, потому что там я обнаружил ответ который работает.Но код который вы показываете в качестве примера, я пробовал в практике, у меня не работает, и код чуть не понятен, почему вызывается функция 
addXMLRequestCallback(function (xhr) два раза?

Comment: @BahodirBahodir изменил ответ.